# Generator function with name

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, bluebird

I have just started using Bluebird's [Promise.coroutine](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html) which is a promise version of [Generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) from ES6.

Everything works fine when I create a function and put it in a variable. Like:

```
let success = Promise.coroutine(function* (_context) {
    ...
});

exports.success = Promise.coroutine(function* (_context) {
    ...
});
```

But when I try to create an standalone function. Like:

```
Promise.coroutine(function *success() {
    ...
});
```

It never defines a function and I get the error:

> success is not defined

How do I access an standalone generator function? or more straight forward, how to create it?

**Edit:**

I am using validatejs, it requires success and error functions for async validations:

```
exports.create = function (req, res) {

    var constraints = {
        ...
    }

    validate.async(req, constraints).then(Promise.coroutine(success), Promise.coroutine(error));

    function success() {    //generator
    }

    function error(e) {     //generator
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show where the error is thrown? Where do you try to access `success`?

Comment: That was the error, actually `success` was never defined. So it an error for calling an undefined object in JS. Got it solved now as `Agalo` suggested.

Comment: But then you still miss the part where you try to use `success`. The error shown results in a part of you code that you didn't show in your question.

Comment: I've added the line where I had to pass the function.

Comment: The name of a function no matter if generator or not, is only accessible from within the function, if this function is directly used as argument. For `foo(function bar() {})`  the `bar` will also only be accessible from within the `bar` function itself. The same is with `var foo = { bar : function bar() {}};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a generator function as shown below.

```
function* functionName([param[, param[, ... param]]]) {
   statements..
}
```

Please note that symbol * is with word **function** and not the functionname. The declaration function keyword followed by an asterisk defines a generator function.

**Update1:** Usage with the Promise.coroutine method. In javascript, function are first class citizen and hence can be passed as an parameter. So, you can replace the function expression with the functionname.

```
Promise.coroutine(functionName);
```

Comment: and how to wrap it in **coroutine**?

Comment: I haven't used the Bluebird's Promise.coroutine. But, i beleive you can pass it as a function argument as it is expecting a function as a parameter.

Comment: @t.niese Yes you're right. He wrote incorrect but explained correctly :)

Comment: I don't think that's entirely correct. The problem is that you are trying to call `success()` but that is not really defined in your context (or scope actually).

Comment: @migueldiab It is, you can refer to question for details where I defined and where I called.

Answer (score 0):

Your `success()` function doesn't have to be named because you are actualyy not calling that, but calling the coroutine Promise. See the example below. You should assign your coroutine to whatever you are trying to call it from, and then yield a Promise for your delayed processing (whatever that may be). Then you need to call the coroutine that will take care of returning the promise.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

function Test() {

}

Test.prototype.foo = Promise.coroutine(function* success() {
  console.log("Called success")
  var i = 0;

  while (i < 3) {
    console.log("Waiting and Yield " + i++);
    yield Promise.delay(1000);
  }
  console.log("Test " + i);
});


var a = new Test();
a.foo();
console.log("Done!");
```

Then you will get this output :

```
>node index.js
Called success
Waiting and Yield 0
Done!
Waiting and Yield 1
Waiting and Yield 2
Test 3
```

Comment: I am doing exactly the same where I need it, but I had a slight different scenario *explained in the question* where I didn't want to create a new variable to hold my function.